# How to use QtCreator for Arduino sketches (ino)

Tags: qt, qt-creator, syntax-highlighting, arduino-ide

I kind of like QtCreator as an IDE for not just a Qt projects. And I really do not like the Arduino IDE. So I'm trying to edit the INO files in QtCreator. It was fine for older version of Qt but now with the latest one 9.0.0 I have a problem with syntax highlighter and auto-completition. Of course, it is because of the INO extension of source files instead of C extension.

Unfortunately I can not rename the *.ino files to *.c files because the Arduino IDE expects the INO files.

Kind of specialty I know but is there a way to force QtCreator to analyze the *.ino files?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit->Preferences->Environment->MIME Types and append the *.ino extensions to `text/x-c++src`, then QtCreator will treat them as c++ source files (or you can add a new MIME Types and use the C++ Editor as the handler for *.ino files).